# Intel GMA's Video Overlay changes don't take effect

Tags: display

The Intel GMA's Video overlay changes to any of the sliders won't affect my monitor. I see the changes in the preview window but they don't apply onto my screen even if I press Apply and restart my computer.

The colors are abit too saturated for some reason on my screen and I need to fix it, but Intel GMA is the only tool that seems to offer that fix since my monitor's built in menu doesn't have color saturation slider.

Answer (score 0):

If the "video overlay changes" do not affect what you see on the screen, then your GPU is not in the overlay mode.  Overlay mode is typically only used for media/video playback.  The saturation control relates to composite video and the HSV color model.

Try making changes to the Display, Color Enhancement menu. You'll have to use the RGB gamma controls to adjust the color saturation level.  There is no single/simple "saturation" control in the CIE color model that a RGB processor/display uses.